# How to plot a log scale density curve in R ranging till the extreme values?

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot some data in log scale, but the density curve drawn by R does not start from the first extreme data point I have.

Here are some test data and the command I used:

```
d = c(1,1,1,2,4,7,10,20,40,100,200,600,1000,3000,15000,23000)
plot(density(d), log='x', xlim=c(1,23000))
```

Unfortunately, I have not enough reputation points to post an image, but if you type these two lines, it should appear a plot ranging from about 12 instead of 1 (first data point).
Any idea to fix this?

Thank to all of you!

Comment: Check the content of `density(d)`; is it what you expect it to be? I have a hard time understanding exactly what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Is `hist(log(d))` something that would look like what you are after (though not binned)?

Comment: If you simply plot it, you can see that the curve does not span over the full data range (which is from 1 to 23000). The content of density(d) does not answer my question. Also, I do not want to plot the histogram of the log of my data, I just want to plot the density curve using a log scale on the x axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at

```
plot(density(d), xlim=c(-100,100), type="b")
```

You will see that it takes particular values both positive and negative.  The negative values of x will not show up in a logarithmic scale and the smallest positive value is

```
> min( density(d)$x[density(d)$x >0] )
[1] 13.72479
```

causing what you see.  You could prevent the density estimate going to 0 or below with something like

```
plot(density(d, from=0.000001), log='x', xlim=c(1,23000))
```

which would look like this

[image]